# React component not taking into account CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using this React component https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-flipcard.

I am trying to specify its size like this:

```
<FlipCard type="vertical" className="largeDiv">
                <div>Bad!!!!</div>
                <div>Good!!!!</div>
 </FlipCard>
```

Using this `css` file:

```
.largeDiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Imported like this:

```
import '../assets/style.css';
```

I changed its size in the `css` but still in the page, the Flipcard has a small size which doesn't change:

[image]

I also tried like this:

```
<FlipCard type="vertical" style={{width: '500px',height: '500px'}}>
```

but with no effect.

Is there any way I can specify the size of an imported module.
Is there any `css` missing?

Comment: https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-flipcard/blob/master/lib/components/FlipCard.js#L132 It doesn't look like the module author is passing down `style` or `className` props. you could use the selector `ReactFlipCard` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the source of FlipCard.js, it doesn't appear as though this component accepts `className` as props, meaning you won't be able to pipe your CSS class down to the inner HTML elements:

https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-flipcard/blob/master/lib/components/FlipCard.js

Moreover, the author of the component appears to be setting their own `className` at the root level of the component, based on some available `props` like `flipped` or `disabled`:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={cx({
          'ReactFlipCard': true,
          'ReactFlipCard--vertical': this.props.type === 'vertical',
          'ReactFlipCard--horizontal': this.props.type !== 'vertical',
          'ReactFlipCard--flipped': this.state.isFlipped,
          'ReactFlipCard--enabled': !this.props.disabled
        })}
        ....
```

I've found this to be quite common with 3rd-party component libraries. More often than not, I find myself trying to shoehorn functionality or styles into a component that wasn't designed for flexibility. As such, I often peruse 3rd-party components for inspiration, then simply rewrite to meet my needs.

Comment: I understand. However, the imported component is very small(unlike the one in the demo). It looks like its `css` is not imported.